# How can I use OAUTH on Salesforce Live Agent REST API

Tags: rest, liveagent, oauth

We want to use OAUTH - userid/password flow to access salesforce live agent rest API. We have implemented this for other rest api provided by salesforce. 
However the live agent rest api are wide open and we do not see a way to restrict the access. We want the api calls to work only with an oauth access token. How do we achieve this?

Comment: I don't think it's possible... We are facing this issue since long time... Even Salesforce support is not able to provide any workaround yet!

Comment: Thanks Ayub, were you able to find any workaround to prevent unauthorized users from accessing chat?

Comment: I'm wondering who marked this question negative. It's pretty valid question!

Answer (score 0):

The Live Agent APIs are not wide-open - they require the affinity token (based on previously established session) and a session key. It's true that these APIs do not support oAuth but you can fix that. Deploy your own, custom REST API that functions as a proxy - when receiving a call from your client application, your API can construct a new HTTP request, call Live Agent APIs and send the response from Live Agent back to your client app. Your API will have an oAuth interface for authorization.

Comment: The session/affinity keys are fetched using /chat/rest/System/SessionId API which again is wide open. Anybody can access this on http, generate the session and affinity and then use these to make subsequent API callouts.
Building my own REST api wrapper and protecting it with OAUTH still does not solve the problem. Anybody who wants to bypass security will simply not use my API but directly access the salesforce REST API.

Comment: @Anuja The URL to the API endpoint is randomly generated but that is very weak security, you're right. I recommend you file an Idea on [Success](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaSearch) with your proposed enhancement.